# Como acessar uma função não explícita

Tags: javascript

Peço desculpas pelo Título bem genérico, mas não sei expressar isso de forma curta e é por este motivo que minhas pesquisas foram um fracasso.

Vamos logo á um exemplo:

```
bd.colection.find();
```

estou tentando ao invés de declarar explicitamente o find(), fazer assim:

```
const example = {method: 'find'};
bd.collection.example.method();
```

Acessar uma função por string, algo assim

Comment: Não sei se chamando `bd.collection.example.method()` irá funcionar, pois `example` é uma constante e não pertence aos métodos de `collection`, agora se for chamar `example.method()` irá funcionar apenas se o valor de `method` é uma função.

Comment: @DouglasGarrido esse é meu problema, quero acessar uma função do `collection`, mas eu não sei qual será essa função, o papel vai ficar para `const example` que irá ter o nome dá função que a `collection` tem e executá-la

Comment: Então você atribui a função `example` para uma propriedade "genérica" da `collection`. Exemplo: `collection.myFunction = example.method`. Assim você conseguirá chamar: `collection.myFunction()`, pois a propriedade `myFunction` fará parte da sua `collection` e ela é a função recebidada de `example.method`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se entendi bem, o problema é fazer a chamada de um método de `bd.collection`, através de uma `string`, com o nome do método, que vem de outro local do código, provavelmente. Algo como: chame o método especificado em `example.method`, seja ele qual for.

Suponha a situação:

```
var bd = {
  collection: {
    find: function (keyword) {
      console.log(keyword);
    }
  }
}
```

Em que o método é especificado em:

```
const example = {method: "find"};
```

Uma maneira é acessar o objeto por índice, através do nome do método:

```
bd.collection[example.method]("SOpt");
```

Que gera exatamente a mesma saída que a chamada direta do método:

```
bd.collection.find("SOpt");
```

Abaixo, inseri o código completo para poder ser executado.

---

```js
var bd = {
  collection: {
    find: function (keyword) {
      console.log(keyword);
    }
  }
}

const example = {method: "find"};

bd.collection[example.method]("SOpt");
bd.collection.find("SOpt");
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, exatamente isso.